# DirectX 11 Blending transparent objects, not desirable result

Tags: directx, direct3d

I'm trying to implement transparent objects in D3D11. I've setup my blend state like this:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc;

ZeroMemory(&blendDesc, sizeof (D3D11_BLEND_DESC));


blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = TRUE;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL; //0x0f;
// set blending
m_d3dDevice->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &blendState);

float blendFactor[4] = {1,1,1, 1 };
m_d3dContext->OMSetBlendState(blendState, blendFactor, 0xffffffff);
```

Rendering transparent object on top of nontransparent object looks fine. Problem is, when I draw transparent object, and another transparent object on top of it, their colors add up and are less transparent. How to prevent this? Thank you very much

Comment: Please post a screenshot. Of course, two transparent objects together are less transparent than each single one.

Answer (score 1):

Your alphablending follows the formula `ResultingColor = alpha * BackbufferColor + (1-alpha) * RenderedColor`. At the overlapping parts of your transparent objects this formula will be applied twice. For example if your alpha is 0.5, the first object will replace the backbuffercolor for 50%. The second object interpolates its color for 50% from the previous color, which is 50% background and 50% first object, leading to a total of 25% of your background. This is why overlapping transparent objects looks more oqaque.

If you want an equal transparency over the whole screen, you could render your transparent objects onto a offscreen texture. Afterwards you render this texture over the backbuffer with a fix transparency or encode the transparency in the texture if you need different values.